# Is there a keyboard shortcut to get to the Apps section in "new tab" in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

When one uses the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut, a new tab is opened which lists your frequently visited sites (or pinned sites). At the bottom of the page, there is the "Apps" link which will, when selected, display a list of installed applications.

Is there a keyboard shortcut that will allow me to get to the Apps sections of the 'New Tab' page?

[image: Google Chrome's new tab page]

Chrome Version: 14.0.794.0 on WinXP/Win7

Comment: are you using a Mac or PC?

Comment: @wizlog - winxp and win7

Comment: this is ridculous!!!! how is my question, posted in July 2011 a duplicate of a question posted in October 2011.

Comment: @Ahmad: My mistake. Tabs got mixed up. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome opens a new tab of previously used section i.e. Most visited/Apps. Keyboard shortcut to switch between these sections is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>