# Is there a keyboard shortcut to switch between the most visited and apps screens?

Tags: google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a keyboard shortcut to get to the Apps section in “new tab” in Google Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/309935/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-get-to-the-apps-section-in-new-tab-in-google-c)

Is there a keyboard shortcut to switch between the two screens (most visited, apps)?

[image]

Comment: @techie007, I'm referring about the new page, released yesterday. That question is from one year ago, referring to an old version of Chrome. That's why I asked the question again. The "new tab" page has been completely redesigned.

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard shortcut to switch between Most Visited/Apps sections is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>